# What does {0} mean in a PHP statement?

Tags: php

Apols if this has been asked before.  I am using someone else's PHP code and came across the following line:

```
if($_GET['file']{0}=='.') die('Wrong file!');
```

The if, $_GET and die I understand, but what is the meaning of the {0} after the $_GET['file']?  I've looked through a number of tutorials and didn't come across the answer.

TIA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$str{0}` will return the first character/byte of a string. But [the syntax `$str{0}` is deprecated in favor of `$str[0]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> **Note:** Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in `$str{42}`, for the same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use square brackets instead, such as `$str[42]`.

If you’re working with multi-byte characters, use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) instead.

Comment: +1 for mentioning it is deprecated. **DO NOT USE THIS NOTATION!**

Comment: Thx for the comprehensive answer to the question.

Comment: **USE THIS NOTATION IF YOU WANT TO!**  (don't always believe what you read in the manual) :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `{0}` is the same as `[0]`.  So, `$_GET['file']{0}` is getting the zeroth character from `$_GET['files']`.

Comment: not true; you make it sound like [] and {} are the same. they're not. {} is a string index - ie the character at string position x.

Comment: @Rocket: Sorry, I was malinformed. But now I cannot change my vote anymore :( Seems like the vote is locked after 5 minutes.

Comment: +1 I edited your answer (added a newline at end) to be able to change my vote.

Comment: According to Gumbo, using `{}` is deprecated, using `[]` is preferred.

Comment: @Rocket: According to *the PHP manual*, using `{}` is deprecated, using `[]` is preferred. I’m not making the rules. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's shorthand for accessing the first character of the string. $_GET['file']{1} would be the second character, and so on. So in your example it's checking to see whether the first character is a dot, and if so, exiting; presumably to avoid people passing paths in the URL such as ../../../etc/passwd.

Comment: But keep in mind, that this "check" is not enough. One can just use "/etc/passwd" directly and there are various attack vectors for file systems.. See http://www.evilaliv3.org/articles/php-filesystem-attack-vectors/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tim and for the link Jan.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's looking at string position 0 in the variable $_GET['file'] and throwing an error if that happens to be a dot.

This looks like a (relatively crude) way of preventing hack attacks by blocking the user if he tries to access a file that starts with a dot.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the point of the check - was also a mystery.